# MDS Leaf error codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, master-data-services, mds

I am attempting to insert data into a leaf entity within master data services and receiving a error code 256.

Checking microsoft documentation such as the below and I cannot find this code. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/staging-process-errors-master-data-services

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are seeing bitmask which points to error code 300002.
This can be found from table `[mdm].[tblErrorCodesMapping]`.
Usually it is more straightforward to check errors from relevant view `stg.viw_Tablename_MemberErrorDetails`. Error code above is mentioned in documentation of MS.

Br,
PA